# Printing JSON as a list in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to print JSON data ([this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1LnggGOJsrZy1xIpcEf2JJO14g-_UjGq5/view?usp=sharing)) in React. I came to this:

```
const print = data.forEach(e => {
    e.data.map(el => {
      return(
        <li>{el.account_id}</li>
      )
    })
  });
  return (
    <div>
      <ul>
        {print}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
```

Yet it doesn't work (when i do `console.log(el.account_id)` it logs everything, but doesn't display the data in the `ul`). What am i doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

```
const print = data.map(e => {
        return e.data.map(el => {
          return(
            <li>{el.account_id}</li>
          )
        })
      });
return (
   <div>
      <ul>
        {print}
      </ul>
   </div>
);
```

is the correct way to do it.

Comment: @Andy - print is a variable, that should be OK. The core issue is forEach doesn't return the elements being constructed.

Comment: i changed the code to `const print = data.map(e => {return e.data.map(el =>{return...` and now it works, thanks for help :)

Comment: you can accept the answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're very close. `forEach` does not return anything. Use `map`.

You probably want something closer to this:

```
const print = data.map(record => (
  <div key={record.meta.page}>
    <h3>PAGE: {record.meta.page}</h3>
    <ul>
      {record.data.map(item => {
        return (<li key={item.account_id}>{item.account_id}</li>)
      })
      }
    </ul>
  </div>
))

return (
  <div>
    {print}
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const print = data.map(el => {
  return(
    <li>{el.account_id}</li>
  )
})
return (
  <div>
    <ul>
      {print}
    </ul>
  </div>
);
```

you dont need the forEach